# Mysql Constraint on group of rows

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot

I have a situation where i have a chatbot which can support multiple languages . To store this relationship in sql I have created Bot and language mapping table which if bot have 3 languages will create 3 rows in mapping table in mysql. I also have another column called `is_primary` in this mapping table which tells whether this is the bot's primary language. Here i want to ensure that the bot always have atleast and atmost one primary langauge. Is there a way to put constraint in combination of rows to ensure this.

Thanks

Comment: To ensure this condition  on database level in MySQL you'll need to create three triggers. Unique index wont help much.

Comment: @olegsv yeah can do that but first will try to find simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, we cannot have such constraint, and this has to be managed in code

However, instead of using is_primary field, if you normalize the structure and have a separate table for bot and language mapping then you can use composite primary key to ensure each both has exactly one primary language.